# What should I do when I get serial up voting?

Tags: support, serial-voting, voting-fraud, account-suspension

Overnight I have found that I've got +125 by someone upvoting almost all the questions I have posted. What should I do now to get SO not to take me to task for vote fraud?

[image]

Comment: Have you waited 24h for auto-reversals yet?

Comment: No. I just saw it. And reading more about such scenarios, I saw I have to wait 24 hours.

Comment: A random user serially voting your contributions will be not held against you.

Comment: Well that is good news

Comment: Seems like this is now resolved.

Comment: @SecurityHound Unless it's detected (possibly wrongly) that that account is also operated by you.

Comment: @user202729 There is no reason for me to raise a support flag if I did it myself - anyway the points will be removed.

Comment: I know that, just saying.